# Is there any name for the mathematical operation $p(x) \approx p(x_a)p( x_b)$?

Tags: probability-theory

Let $\mathbf{x}$ be a set of random variables/vectors. If we got a partition of $\mathbf{x}$, say $\{\mathbf{x}_a, \mathbf{x}_b\}$ such that

$$p(x) \approx p(x_a)p(x_b),$$

then what is the name of this mathematical operation given above, or what can we call the partition $\{\mathbf{x}_a, \mathbf{x}_b\}$.

Comment: Would this be to say that the set of random variables $\mathbb{x}_a$ is independent of the set of random variables $\mathbb{x}_b$?

Comment: @Bob1123 Thanks. I think they are nearly independent. For example, $\|p(x) - p(x_a)p(x_b)\| \leq \epsilon$. But for any other partition $\{\mathbf{x}_c, \mathbf{x}_d\}$, $\|p(x) - p(x_c)p(x_d)\| > \epsilon$ holds.